# C# WPF passing data between two windows on variable change or buttonclick

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am currently working on a little project in C# with WPF and I need to pass data between two windows (shown below) I can pass the data using a class but I want to show the data in the `TextBox` `“Tb_kunden_id“` (Window one) and it should happen on the click of `“Btn_kunde_hinzufügen_Click “` (Window2) or whenever the variable `“kunden_id_chaged“` (variable is in the class) is changed. The input of the data is changed on a button click (`Btn_kunde_hinzufügen_Click`) Button out of a list of an item. Do I need to add the XAML?

**Window1:**

```
public partial class bestellung_hinzufügen : Window
{
    string login = Login_info.login;
    string datum = "";
    int m_id_auslesen = 0;

    public bestellung_hinzufügen()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        NpgsqlConnection connection = new NpgsqlConnection(login);
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
        }

        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("faild");
        }
         //Some SQL in here
    }


    private void Btn_kunde_suchen_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //I am opening the Window for new Input
        Auswahl_kunde_bestellung auswahl_Kunde_Bestellung = new Auswahl_kunde_bestellung();
        auswahl_Kunde_Bestellung.Show();
    }

    private void Btn_abbrechen_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }


}

//Class that passes the data between different windows
public static class Informationen_bestellungen
{
    public static string kunden_id;
    public static bool kunden_id_chaged = false;
}
```

**Window2:**

```
  public partial class Auswahl_kunde_bestellung : Window
 {
    string login = Login_info.login;
    string suchanfrage = "";

    public Auswahl_kunde_bestellung()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Btn_suchen_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //What I am adding to the list
        suchanfrage = Tb_suchanfrage_kunde.Text;
        Liste_ausgabe_kunden.Items.Clear();
        if (Combo_auswahl_kunde.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            string command_text = "select * from tbl_kunde where k_id >= '" + suchanfrage + "' order by k_id;";
            Ausgabe_kunde(command_text);
        }

        if (Combo_auswahl_kunde.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            string command_text = "select * from tbl_kunde where name like '" + suchanfrage + "%' order by k_id;";
            Ausgabe_kunde(command_text);
        }           
    }
    //Where I want it to update
    private void Btn_kunde_hinzufügen_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Liste_ausgabe_kunden.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            string delete = Liste_ausgabe_kunden.SelectedItem.ToString();
            string[] split_delete = delete.Split();
            //the next line I want to show in the TextBox
            Informationen_bestellungen.kunden_id = split_delete[0];
            Informationen_bestellungen.kunden_id_chaged = true; 
            //Where the TextBox should be changed
            this.Close();
        }
    }

    private void Btn_abbrechen_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void Ausgabe_kunde(string command_text)
    {
       //Some more SQL
    }        
}
```

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: You will need other things possibly as well so prepare your design for it. Create a ViewModel for the main window and this ViewModel will coordinate to pass data between the 2 other ViewModels for the other windows. And yes use XAML and databinding because that is where the power of WPF lies.

Comment: add code blocks to codes inside paragraph